# Adding a cover page for appendices and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, appendices

I need to add two cover pages (plain page with centered text) in front of my appendices and bibliography to satisfy the typographical requirements of my graduate school. They must be treated as part of the appendices and bibliography, i.e. the entry in the table of contents defining the start of the appendices or bibliography should refer to the cover pages.

Any ideas?

I've included a stripped version of the main document below.

Thank you!

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

% \usepackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[light,partialup,largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}  

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable,ltcaption}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\hmmax}{0}
\newcommand{\bmmax}{2}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xspace}



\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}%
  {\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}


\begin{document}


% FRONT MATTER: TITLE, ABSTRACT, DEDICATION, AND THANKS

\pagestyle{empty}           
\pagenumbering{roman}       
\include{prelim/title}
\doublespace
\include{prelim/abstract}
\include{prelim/copyright}
\pagestyle{plain}       
\include{prelim/dedication}
\include{prelim/thanks}


% TABLE OF CONTENTS, LIST OF FIGURES, TABLE OF TABLES

\singlespace
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables 

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\doublespacing


% MAIN BODY OF THESIS
% -------------------
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}               
\pagenumbering{arabic}          
\include{ch01_intro/chapter01}
% Other chapters emitted for brevity


% APPENDICES

\appendix
\clearemptydoublepage
\include{appendices/appendix1}
% Other appendices ommitted
\clearemptydoublepage

% End matter:
\pagestyle{plain}
\singlespace
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\textit{Bibliography}}
\bibliography{references}
\clearemptydoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hy @Sean, did my answer helped you? If yes it would be nice to accept my answer so we both get some reputations points. If no, pleas tell me whats wrong/missing?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\part*{Bibliography}`, which gives an empty page with the Title but without a hyperref link.

It is more difficult to get the right link because you have to hack the ToC entry for Appendix/Bibliography and set an anchor on the title pages.

### Update

This seems to work

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% Main matter
\chapter{Chap One}
\Blindtext[5]

\chapter{Chap Two}
\Blindtext[3]

\appendix
\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\chapter{App One}
\blindtext[7]

\chapter{App Two}
\blindtext[7]

\part*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

%\bibliography{references}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```